# MySQL Create DB If Not Exists With File Import Command Line

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm using a command like:

```
mysql db < db.sql
```

But whenever I do this with a DB that doesn't already exist, it errors.

Is there a command flag to add to that to create the DB if it doesn't exist?
Or a line of code to insert into the start of the file?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution for me was to write a PHP program to iterate through each db's sql file and do the following:

```
/*
$mysqldir being where the mysql exe is installed too.
$db being the database name
$file being where the sql file is
*/

$exec_str = "\"".$mysqldir."mysql\" -h localhost -u {username} -p{password} -e \"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `".$db."`\"";
system($exec_str, $status);
$exec_str = "\"".$mysqldir."mysql\" -h localhost -u {username} -p{password} ".$db." < \"".$file."\"";
system($exec_str, $status);
```

Basically: (Partially what @Drew answered with)

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database_name`
`database_name` < "C:\file\file2\db.sql"
```

from the mysql command line.

Answer (score 3):

do you mean like these two lines?

```
create schema if not exists myNewDb;
use myNewDb;    -- make it the active one
```

The second command will select the db (whether or not it just created it).

Comment: Yes I ended up doing somethine similar. I got PHP to run first the mysql command with CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname
then I got it to run again with my original command and that fixed my issues.

Comment: Great. Perhaps you can check mark it as Answered then. Perhaps others will find it helpful, even though you asked the question.